# For the latest version of Lucene(4.8.0) ,how to custom scoring rules

Tags: lucene.net

In Lucene *(v3.0)* we can use `CustomScoreProvider` and `CustomScoreQuer` to customize scoring.

However, in the latest version of Lucene, I can not find those classes. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

both the classes move to the [Lucene.Net.Queries](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net.Queries/)

And any other change , we can look at [Apache Lucene Migration Guide](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/MIGRATE.html)